# How to find user's home directory on Windows and Linux in PHP

Tags: php, linux, windows, cross-platform

I've understood there are several ways to determine the user's home, depending on the platform (mainly Unix/Linux vs Windows).

Composer uses an environment variable, in [composer/Platform](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/ef46a8afa4f5d845befbc7be832432c4b30d6313/src/Composer/Util/Platform.php#L48) package:

```
public static function getUserDirectory()
{
    if (false !== ($home = getenv('HOME'))) {
        return $home;
    }
    if (self::isWindows() && false !== ($home = getenv('USERPROFILE'))) {
        return $home;
    }
    if (function_exists('posix_getuid') && function_exists('posix_getpwuid')) {
        $info = posix_getpwuid(posix_getuid());
        return $info['dir'];
    }
    throw new \RuntimeException('Could not determine user directory');
}

public static function isWindows()
{
    return defined('PHP_WINDOWS_VERSION_BUILD');
}
```

[Webmozart's path-util](https://github.com/webmozart/path-util/blob/95a8f7ad150c2a3773ff3c3d04f557a24c99cfd2/src/Path.php#L245) package uses other environment variables:

```
public static function getHomeDirectory()
{
    // For UNIX support
    if (getenv('HOME')) {
        return static::canonicalize(getenv('HOME'));
    }
    // For >= Windows8 support
    if (getenv('HOMEDRIVE') && getenv('HOMEPATH')) {
        return static::canonicalize(getenv('HOMEDRIVE').getenv('HOMEPATH'));
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Your environment or operation system isn't supported");
}
```

What is the difference between these two methods? Is one more reliable than the other?
Note: I'm using PHP in the CLI, so it's always the actual current user running PHP.

EDIT> I understand that this question seems to ask for an opinion, but it's not the case. I DO NOT KNOW Windows and do not understand why some packages use different ways to determine the user's home directory. I'm asking for explanations about the two mentioned methods: is one of them more reliable than the other and why?
I've edited the title and the question to reflect this precision.

Comment: Almost all usage of the home directory goes against platform conventions on Windows. Applications should use the shell API for [known folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188) to locate the application local and roaming data directories (used appropriately), per-user programs directory, and other folders such as the user's desktop, documents, and downloads folders.

Comment: `HOME` is not conventional on Windows. Why would a Windows user or admin respect what a Unix developer expects here? Using its value is a fragile design. `USERPROFILE` is where you'll find the core profile file (registry hive), ntuser.dat. This is also the default home directory if an account doesn't have one and the default directory for other known folders. Of course they can all be relocated by the user or policy, so don't assume they're at the default location relative to the user profile directory.

Comment: `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` are for an explicitly set home directory in an account, and otherwise may be set to the same location as `USERPROFILE`, depending on how the user was logged on. Regretfully this value is not reliable at all. For example, the Secondary Logon service (e.g. runas.exe) will set this as `"%SystemRoot%\System32"` (e.g. "C:\Windows\System32"). Good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. How am I supposed to used the folders names in PHP?
According to [Known folder ids](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457) I could use `FOLDERID_LocalAppData` which default is `%LOCALAPPDATA%` (`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local`). How to use `FOLDERID_LocalAppData` in PHP?
If I understand, I could use environment variable `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, but it's the default value, which means it may be different...

Comment: You can rely on `USERPROFILE` (but it goes against convention to create dot files and directories here; Windows is not Unix), `APPDATA` and `LOCALAPPDATA`  if you can't call `SHGetKnownFolderPath` or the older `SHGetFolderPath` function. What you can't rely on is the location of known folders relative to the user profile or the application data directories, such as `FOLDERID_Documents` and `FOLDERID_UserProgramFiles`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess PHP lacks bindings for `SHGetKnownFolderPath` function (while Python seems to have some). I might consider installing a Windows on a virtual machine to see and understand how it is in the reality.Because "code names" like `USERPROFILE`, `APPDATA` and `LOCALAPPDATA` don't mean much to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not working on this for a long time, I finally decided to definitely answer this question.

There are some usefull environment variables defined on Windows: `USERPROFILE`, `APPDATA`, `LOCALAPPDATA`. They are easily accessible via getenv() function:

```php
getenv('USERPROFILE');
```

`USERPROFILE` exists on any Windows, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/shell/knownfolderid

So, on Windows, it seems to be reliable.

If you need to store data for the current user, `APPDATA` and `LOCALAPPDATA` are good variables to find that place.

I've written a package to make these tools reusable: https://github.com/Arcesilas/Platform

It's still work in progress and certainly needs to be improved. Any help is welcome to make this tool reliable on any platform.

Thanks to eryksun whose comments helped a lot in solving this question.